# Replace with Regular Expression does not work correctly with Tab and Line Break patterns

Tags: xcode

Code:

```
struct Test {
    var string: String
    var int: Int
}
```

Searching for:

```
var (.*): Int
```

Replacing with:

```
var $1: Int { didSet { string = String($1) } }
```

Replacing without special patterns works fine. Groups are correctly replaced with `$1` value

```
struct Test {
    var string: String
    var int: Int { didSet { string = String(int) } }
}
```

But if at least one special pattern added, groups will not be replaced, and `"$1"` will be printed instead.

```
var $1: Int {`BR` `TAB` `TAB`didSet { `BR` `TAB` `TAB` `TAB`string = String($1)`BR` `TAB` `TAB` } `BR` `TAB`}
```

```
struct Test {
    var string: String
    var $1: Int { 
        didSet {
            string = String($1)
         }
     }
}
```

[image]
Is this an XCode bug, or am I missing something? 
`XCode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)`

Comment: I actually have no problem replacing using tabs and newlines. The difficult thing is to insert them directly. Create the replacement text outside Xcode and just copy paste the result (including tabs and newlines) to the input field. I have no idea how you are inserting the special characters for them to appear as in your screenshot.

Comment: Ctrl + Option + Command + P. It's available as a button when trying to add replace text for global search.

Comment: It seems that inserts some special pattern which is not supported?

Comment: Anyway, considering the two input fields in global and local replace share state (they always contain the same pattern), it's surprising they have different behavior.